Computing a power diagram
I want to compute the power diagram of a set of points. When the d-spheres overlap, the solution seems straightforward. You construct the d-1 sphere made up by their intersection and then pass a plane through it. The final cell is then made up as the intersection of half spaces made by these planes.
But if the spheres do not intersect, it is less clear to me how to construct the bisector. If the weights between two points are identical, then it stands to reason the bisector is just the euclidean bisector. And it also seems reasonable that as the ratio between the weights of two points increases, the bisector's position would be biased towards the point with lower weight.
But this intuition is insufficient to get an actual position for the bisector.

From wikipedia: "in the power diagram, we may view each circle center as a site, and each circle's squared radius as a weight that is subtracted from the squared Euclidean distance before comparing it to other squared distances."

From wikipedia:

in the power diagram, we may view each circle center as a site, and
each circle's squared radius as a weight that is subtracted from the
squared Euclidean distance before comparing it to other squared
distances.

Suppose you have the balls $B_1 = B_{(c_1, R_1)}$ and $B_2 = B_{(c_2, R_2)}$ and $p=(1-t) c_1 + tc_2$. The power of $p$ wrt $B_1$ is $\|p-c_1\|^2 - R_1^2 = t^2 \|c_2 - c_1\|^2 - R_1^2$. Similarly the power of $p$ wrt $B_2$ is $\|p-c_2\|^2 - R_2^2 = (1-t)^2\|c_2-c_1\|^2 - R_2^2$. Make the two expressions equal and try to solve for $t$:
\begin{align}
t^2 \|c_2 - c_1\|^2 - R_1^2 &= (1-t)^2\|c_2-c_1\|^2 - R_2^2 \\
2t \|c_2-c_1\|^2 &= R_1^2 - R^2_2 + \|c_2-c_1\|^2 \\
t &= \frac{R_1^2-R_2^2}{2\|c_2-c_1\|^2} + \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
